# How one can be notified that a variable goes out of scope in Workflow Foundation 4?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

We are using Workflow Foundation 4 to implement custom logic in our application. One particular thing is that we are using variables of a custom type that are associated with a ressource in an external system.

When such a variable is no longer in use in a workflow, I would like to dispose of the corresponding resource in the external system.

How can my custom host be notified at runtime that my variable goes out of scope and/or is disposed. Do I need my variable objects to derive from a particular class or interface ? Do I need to inject a particular extension in the workflow instance ?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to implement a custom `TrackingParticipant`. This can be used to watch for when an activity's state changes to a closed state. When it is closed, you can inspect the arguments to see if any are of a resource that you'd like to clean up.

It could look something like this:

```
public interface IResource
{
}

public class MyTrackingParticipant : TrackingParticipant
{
    private readonly MyResourceManager resourceManager;

    public MyTrackingParticipant(MyResourceManager resourceManager)
    {
        this.resourceManager = resourceManager;
    }

    protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var activityStateRecord = record as ActivityStateRecord;
        if (activityStateRecord != null && activityStateRecord.State == ActivityStates.Closed)
        {
            // Scan arguments to see if resources should be deallocated from resource manager.
            foreach (var keyValuePair in activityStateRecord.Arguments)
            {
                // If the argument is of a resource type... 
                var resource = keyValuePair.Value as IResource;
                if (resource != null)
                    this.resourceManager.DeallocateResource(resource);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And using the custom tracking participant is just like any other WF extension:

```
var resourceManager = new MyResourceManager();
var wfResourceTrackingParticipant = new MyTrackingParticipant(resourceManager);
var workflow1 = new Workflow1();
var workflowApp = new WorkflowApplication(workflow1);
workflowApp.Extensions.Add(wfResourceTrackingParticipant);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, I'm after *automatic* notifications as whether the variables I use are not longer needed. I would not like the author of the WF sprinkle the workflow with an explicit "CleanupActivity".

Comment: After thinking about it a bit more, implementing a custom tracking participant maybe the way to go. I updated my answer to reflect this approach.

Comment: Awesome, that is in line with what I'm looking for, thanks. I'll try that and let you know.